# I think my server is broken, files that do not exist are showing up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, google-chrome

I deleted a javascript file from my website and instead of showing 404, even after deleting the cache and restarting my PC, chrome is showing that the file still exists. As is firefox and IE.

How do I get the browsers to update, or is this just my server's fault

Comment: How did you delete it from the server? Can you still see the file on your server?

Comment: What kind of caching are you using? Who's your host? If you leave the network you're currently on, does it 404 there? This question is extremely vague.

Answer (score -1):

If your JS file is public, try to get it with this terminal command:

```
wget yoursice.com/your/file/path/youfile.js
```

If it doesn't give you an error, and download your file, mean that the file it's not deleted...